# Change java class superclass with reflection

Tags: java, reflection

Is it possible to change the inheritance hierarchy of class objects at runtime with reflection?

My situation is I have:

SuperClass

MiddleClass extends SuperClass

BottomClass extends SuperClass

I would like to use reflection at runtime to change BottomClass to extend MiddleClass. Is this possible?

THanks

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this?

Comment: I'm modifying an existing package and have a customized extension of an object provided by it.  I would like those customizations to trickle down to the child classes of the parent I customized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible through reflection becuase reflection is used to analyze the existing code, not to change it.

Comment: You *can* however change constants (`static final` fields) with it.

Comment: Yes, there are small modifications which can be made through reflection. But I would say this not changing the code per se, this is merely a modification of how it is accessed.

Comment: @KimMens I said that it can't be done using reflection. Is instrumentation reflection? No. Then what did I say wrong?

Comment: @Malcolm I redraw my comment as after some reflection (pun intended) I see now that the terminology could be debatable. Whereas I would have regarded instrumentation as a kind of reflection at the level of byte-code and at class loading time, it is true that it is perhaps not reflection in the strict sense of manipulating entities reflectively at run-time at meta-level through a well-defined meta-object protocol. Though advanced byte-code manipulation libraries also offer you some kind of meta-object protocol to some extent.

Comment: @KimMens I'm glad you agree with me. I saw the following text in the official documentation: "Reflection allows programmatic access to information about the fields, methods and constructors of loaded classes, and the use of reflected fields, methods, and constructors to operate on their underlying counterparts, within security restrictions." In short, information and use, but not modification. So that's the basis of my understanding. Of course, there may be other definitions I'm not aware of.

Comment: The problem is that reflection is pretty broad and some use the term more strictly than others. It depends on your definition. If you refer to the Java definition of relection through java.lang.reflect the definition is more narrow. E.g. in Python you can manipulate a class at run-time by manipulating the dictionary in terms of which it is implemented. Is this reflection or not? On the one hand you do manipulate it at runtime through some operations that give you access to that dict, on the other hand it feels more low level than going "meta". Some would still call this reflection, others not

Comment: @KimMens I just picked the definition which looked most relevant to the question and stuck to it. To my mind, terminology in software development is always somewhat inexact.

Answer (score 6):

The closest you can get to this with Java is [instrumentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html).  Basically you write some Java classes which are given the series of bytes which define a class, muck around with the byte code, and return the modified class file byte array.  You then package these classes up in a JAR file and tell the JVM to use them, either on the command line or by putting an attribute into the manifest file of the instrumentation JAR file.

Of course, if you do this, you'd want to use some byte code manipulation library like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/).

**EDIT**: If the class you're interested in implements interfaces you might want to take a look at [dynamic proxy classes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) via [java.lang.reflect.Proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).  This has the disadvantage that pieces of code which you didn't write which do `new ClassOfInterest()` are unaffected, but has the advantages of:

1. Being a lot easier than modifying the byte code of classes.
2. You can dynamically choose to make different instances of the proxies act like they have different superclassess.
3. You don't have to worry about any `SecurityManager` issues.

Answer (score -1):

Inheritance is static, so it cannot be changed at runtime.

However you could make `SuperClass` an interface or use delegation instead of inheritance.

Answer (score -2):

it is not possible.For example if you already have an object of BottomClass and you are trying to change super class, what will happen to that object? it's impossible...